# Выбор случайных значений из разных списков

Tags: python, list

Есть списки:

```
symbols_list = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '?', '*', '(', ')', '{', '}', '~']
figures_list = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
letters_list = ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O' итак далее.. ]
```

Мне необходимо как-то сделать, чтобы в переменную добавлялся один символ из случайного списка. Как можно сделать что-то такое, маленьким кодом:

```
password += random.choice(symbols_list, figures_list, letters_list)
```

Comment: Вариант раз: `random.choice(symbols_list + figures_list + letters_list)`

Comment: Вариант два: `random.choice(random.choice([symbols_list, figures_list, letters_list]))`

Comment: По теории вероятности эти два варианта дадут РАЗНЫЕ результаты, и какой результат нужен вам — вам виднее

Comment: Спасибо, не знал что так можно, рад что есть люди которые помогают ночью. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант раз:

```
random.choice(symbols_list + figures_list + letters_list)
```

Вариант два:

```
random.choice(random.choice([symbols_list, figures_list, letters_list]))
```

По теории вероятности эти два варианта дадут **РАЗНЫЕ** результаты, и какой результат нужен вам — вам виднее

<sub>@andreymal — из комментариев</sub>

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

list_one = ['1', '2', '3']
list_two = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_three = ['-', '/', '_']

common_list = [list_one, list_two, list_three]
password = ''

def append_symbol():
    random_list = common_list[random.randrange(len(common_list))]
    random_element = random_list[random.randrange(len(random_list))]

    return random_element

for i in range(10):
    password += append_symbol()
```

#### Либо

```
password += random.choice(random.choice(common_list))
```